# Android ListView with different colors

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I am having a little problem using different colors in a `ListView`.

I have tried several things but nothing seems to work

private class GameRowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        ArrayList objects;

```
    public GameRowAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<RowModel> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        RowModelViews model;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(GamePlayerActivity.this);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_line_layout, null);
            model = new RowModelViews();
            model.entry = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.gameLineEntry);
            model.score = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.gameLineEntryScore);
            row.setTag(model);
        } else {
            model = (RowModelViews) row.getTag();
        }

        if (position == 6 || position == 7) {
            row.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
        } else {
            row.setBackgroundColor(R.color.light_transparent);
        }

        model.entry.setText(objects.get(position).entry);
        model.score.setText(objects.get(position).score);

        return row;
    }
}

static class RowModelViews {
    TextView entry;
    TextView score;

}

static class RowModel {
    String entry;
    String score;

    public RowModel(String entry, String score) {
        this.entry = entry;
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

Anyone who can tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Here is the xml of the inflatet row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/gameLineEntry"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
              android:textSize="20dp"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/gameLineEntryScore"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_width="65dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
              android:gravity="center"
              style="@style/Button"                  
              android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: After running a small local test, I think the issue may be that the TextViews you have in each row are in front of the ListView row view. Try setting the model.entry and model.score background colors. /Edit

I think it's coming from the convertViews being reused. Try moving this:

```
if (position == 6 || position == 7) {
    row.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
}
```

Outside of the if (row == null) block, and change it to this:

```
if (position == 6 || position == 7) {
    model.entry.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
    model.score.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);

} else {
    model.entry.setBackgroundColor(/*Whatever your default background color is*/);
    model.score.setBackgroundColor(/*Whatever your default background color is*/);
}
```

So your full getView method would be:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        RowModelViews model;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(GamePlayerActivity.this);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_line_layout, null);
            model = new RowModelViews(row);
            model.entry = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.gameLineEntry);
            model.score = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.gameLineEntryScore);
            row.setTag(model);
        } else {
            model = (RowModelViews) row.getTag();
        }

        if (position == 6 || position == 7) {
            model.entry.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
            model.score.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
        } else {
            model.entry.setBackgroundColor(/*Whatever your default background color is*/);
            model.score.setBackgroundColor(/*Whatever your default background color is*/);
        }

        model.entry.setText(objects.get(position).entry);
        model.score.setText(objects.get(position).score);

        return row;
    }
```

Comment: I can see what you mean. But with this code every line in the ListView get the black color.

Comment: What are you setting the background color to in the position != {6, 7} case in the else clause? If you set it to say, red, you should see all the backgrounds be red except for 6 & 7.

Comment: When position != {6,7} I set the default color. But with your corrections every line gets black??

Comment: That it did not help. All rows still gets black. It's a bit frustrating :(

Comment: Okay. Don't know why. But setting the color to transparent in the else clause instead of the default color works. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You are only defining the color in the creation of the view. However for the recycled views you need to set the color again explicitly. There is no guarantee that 6 and 7 will be new views. So always set the color of the view with each call of getView

Comment: I have tried to set the color for each getView call (see Bernstein answer), but when I do that every line turns black??

Comment: Could you post the new way you tried? Also could you show the xml being inflated?