# Changing color of each item of a listview

Tags: android, listview, colors

I have a listview and I am trying to change color of each item of a listview.
For example:
item 1: Orange Color
item 2: Blue color

I dont want it when it is focused or pressed. It should just appear like this in listview.
I am new to android. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: write a custom adapter, where you can set the layout color based on the position. In the `getView` method

Comment: this post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787503/android-listview-with-different-colors

Comment: I am sorry but can you please explain it a little more.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Baseadapter, you can function in getView();

sample ;

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder   = new ViewHolder();
        CategoryHelper cath     = getItem( position );

        if( convertView == null ) {

            viewHolder                  = new ViewHolder();
            convertView                 = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.site_adapter, parent, false);

            viewHolder.category_title       = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.site_title );

            convertView.setTag( viewHolder );
        }
        else {
            viewHolder          = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if( ( position % 2 ) == 0  ){
            viewHolder.category_title.setTextColor( R.color.pink );
        } else {
            viewHolder.category_title.setTextColor( R.color.pink );
        }
        viewHolder.category_title.setText( cath.getCategory_title() );

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView category_title;
    }
```

Hope can help you.
good luck.